# Rails / AR – how to test ::update(id, attributes) in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I'm using the active record [update](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update) method to update multiple records, each with their own individual attributes.

I facilitate that with this controller code (which works):

```
def update
  keys = params[:schedules].keys
  values = params[:schedules].values
  if Schedule.update(keys, values)
    flash[:notice] = "Schedules were successfully updated."
  else
    flash[:error] = "Unable to update some schedules."
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to responsibilities_path }
  end
end
```

My question is, **how can I test that without hitting the database in rspec**?

Here's what I'm trying, but its not working.

```
describe "PATCH update" do

  it "updates the passed in responsibilities" do
    allow(Schedule)
      .to receive(:update)
      .with(["1", "2"], [{"status"=>"2"}, {"status"=>"1"}])
      .and_return(true)
    # results in
    # expected: 1 time with arguments: (["1", "2"], [{"status"=>"2"}, {"status"=>"1"}])
    # received: 0 times
    # Couldn't find Schedule with 'id'=1

    # without the allow, I get
    # Failure/Error: patch :update, schedules: {
    # ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
    #   Couldn't find Schedule with 'id'=1
    # # ./app/controllers/responsibilities_controller.rb:18:in `update'
    # # ./lib/authenticated_system.rb:75:in `catch_unauthorized'
    # # ./spec/controllers/responsibilities_controller_spec.rb:59:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

    patch :update, schedules: {
      "1" => {
        "status" => "2",
      },
      "2" => {
        "status" => "1",
      }
    }
    expect(Schedule)
      .to receive(:update)
      .with(["1", "2"], [{"status"=>"2"}, {"status"=>"1"}])
    expect(flash[:error]).to eq(nil)
    expect(flash[:notice]).not_to eq(nil)
  end
end
```

I'm on Rails 4.2.4 and rspec 3.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is, that you are expecting with

```
expect(Schedule)
      .to receive(:update)
      .with(["1", "2"], [{"status"=>"2"}, {"status"=>"1"}])
      .and_call_original
```

after calling the patch method.

That means the request hits your controller before the assertion is established.
To solve that, just put the expect(Schedule) call before the patch call, that also allows you to get rid of the allow(Schedule).to - call.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I tried that too, this does avoid the error above, however it doesn't allow me to test changes in the object either.  For example if I want to confirm the status change and I add an assertion for expect(schedule.reload.status).to eq(2), that fails.  Is there a way to maintain that here too?

Comment: You probably need the ".and_call_original" method to achieve that. When you assert method calls, the method does not have to be there, that's kind of a feature there. That means it does not get called without you saying so. Updating my answer to show that.